# Oracle takes more time to export csv

Tags: oracle

Oracle takes more time to export csv,i have tried with UTL_FILE & spool both takes more time,if there are any other way in coding for fastest export?

Comment: The question gives no indication of number of records, columns, datatypes, how long your attempts have taken, the OS and disk set up. You also don't say how long you would expect this to take. The more information you give and the sharing of your own attempts will enable people to possibly give hints that may help you.

Comment: My environment:

DB:Oracle 11g

Exported CSV using UTL_FILE

No of Recorsds:1253259
Time Taken:25 mins
os:Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
No of colomns:4
Datatype:varchar
Disk set up details:
Filesystem                  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/pr--vg-root  225G   28G  187G  13% /
//serverip/share  450G   47G  381G  11% /location/
/dev/sda1                   236M   39M  185M  18% /boot
My expectation:It should happen 45-60 secs
Note:But MSSQL takes only 45 sec to export (using xmd_shell bcp)

Comment: More time then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just thought I'd do a quick test.
Used UTL_FILE to export 4 columns (comma separated) from a table of approx 1.3Million records.
This is the code;

```
DECLARE
fl_output  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
s_output_line   VARCHAR2(2000);

CURSOR lcur_test IS
 SELECT col_a||','||col_b||','||col_c||','||col_d AS line_out
   FROM insurance_policy;

BEGIN
fl_output := utl_file.fopen('OUT_DIR','test_file.csv','w');

FOR lrec_test IN lcur_test
LOOP

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(fl_output, lrec_test.line_out);
END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fl_output);
END;
```

Very simple and produces a file with all the records in 25seconds.
The DB is Oracle 11g (not Enterprise) on Windows and is by no means fast.
I suspect that you may well have a query that is les that optimal and that is where the time is going OR you have something very wrong wit your disks.

Comment: Hi Brite what you said is right,when i write to the file local drive it writes  in 1 minutes,while i write it on network mapped drive it takes more than 20 minutes. Size of the csv created is around 75 MB. I tried my mounting the drive to windows and tried to add in oracle but oracle could it understand my mounted path i.e Z:\. Is there anything i can try other than this. Note- I need to use the mapped drive or server storage only.

Comment: Instead of just Z:\ you will probably need the full path and then share. Remember, the directory should be the name that the Oracle server would know it as, i.e. its full network name. e.g. \\storageserver\dataarea, or something like that.

Comment: We have mapped network drive by going to Mapnetworkdrive in windows,select the drive Z: and then gave the serverpath as //serverip/foldername/ in the path and created it.
Then created directory in oracle using  CREATE DIRECTORY MAPMYDIR AS 'Z:/';GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY MAPMYDIR TO SchemaName;
This configuration made to map remote server storage loaction as local to oracle.
Then i have used "MAPMYDIR" oracle directory in my procedure i got this error,
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation

Comment: if i create the directory in oracle using  CREATE DIRECTORY LOCALDIR AS '//serverip/foldername/';GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY LOCALDIR TO SchemaName;
if i used the oracle directory "LOCALDIR" it works,as i discussed before it takes more than 20 mins.

if i create the directory in oracle using  CREATE DIRECTORY MYLOCALDIR AS 'C:/';GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY MYLOCALDIR TO SchemaName;

if i used the oracle directory "MYLOCALDIR" it works,as i discussed before it takes 1 mins it good & efficient but i need to store the file in another server storage

Comment: It sounds like you need to look at the network set up for this as Oracle is clearly able to do what you want pretty quickly in one situation but is slowed in the other.